# RegExp: How to build a regexp for a list

Tags: regex

I am trying to craft a regular expression for matching the following structure:

```
 []
 [A]
 [A, A]
 [A, A, A]
```

etc..

The best I could reach so far is:

```
\[A?|(A(, A)*)*\]
```

but it is not good enough.

[image]

Comment: @dushkin Still, `(A?|A(, A)*)` is not recommended because the two alternatives can match at the same location in a string, which is not best practice. It decreases performance and in case of larger strings may cause a slowdown. My solution below matches "linearly", consecutively and each subsequent pattern can only match at different locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\[(?:A(?:, A)*)?]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HhFVGS/1)

**Details**

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `(?:A(?:, A)*)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching

  - `A` - an `A`
  - `(?:, A)*` - 0 or more consecutive occurrences of `,`, space and `A`
- `]` - a `]` char.